# How to save multiple similar(hierachical format) string with less memory?

Tags: string, algorithm, memory

I need save such strings in c++, and need do name compare. Is there any algorithm to reduce the memory usage? Thanks.

x1.x2.x3.r1 //typical string lenth is larger than 50.

x1.x2.x3.r2

x1.x2.x3.r3

x1.x2.x4.r1

...

Myself have such plan: divid a string to two parts: "x1.x2.x3.r1" = "x1.x2.x3." ( A ) + "r1"(B), and A can be used in other string. And when compare name need compare two parts. I am not sure if it can work.

Comment: If there are some patterns that occur frequently in the strings then you can code the patterns A, B, C etc and shorten the string lengths. You can compare them in the normal manner.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing them in a tree?

Each node, would represent the next part of the string separated by a dot.

Then, when comparing, you compare the nodes ancestors.

Comment: Hi, All, thanks for your help. 
I test like the tree way, a node need save prenode handle and a name to node map, so seems can not reduce memory.
I also test directly divid the string to two parts, and use set to avoid substring duplication, can reduce memory evidently.

Comment: if you store a pointer to the next node, the memory, when a long enough string is used is reduced. Take for example string aaaaa.b and aaaaa.c. Before, these strings took 5*2 characters or 14 bytes. Putting this in a tree would result in 5 bytes for parent, 2 pointers which sum up to 8 bytes, and 2 bytes for the values.

Comment: I agree with your comment. I think in my case the whole string is not long enough to get evident benefit from tree. 
In my case have about 10 chars between divid char '.', and a string can be divid to 5 substring. 
And I coding on linux 64 version, so a pointer needs 8 bytes. 
A node need a pointer save pernode, a pointer save current string, and a pointer which point to it, so need 3*8 bytes. So in the case origial string size 50 is not much larger than three pointers size 24, cause me can not get expect large memory decrease by use tree.

Comment: actually, a Node would store only a list of children, there is no need to store the parent, so it would be only 2*8 bytes + characters.
And you save x-16 bytes for each new node that shares x bytes with the one you already put in. This seems to be the best way to save memory in this scenario.